# Closing element on click outside - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just doing a quick test on clicking outside an element with jquery, but having some problems.

I'm trying to remove a class on click outside of an element.

The problem appears to be that the 'document' handler is activating at the same time as the span and therefore not working.

I need it so it works after the class has already been added.

Cheers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" media="screen" title="no title">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen" title="no title">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="top-list"><span>Item</span>
                <ul class="sub-top">
                    <li class="sub-list">Item 1</li>
                    <li class="sub-list">Item 2</li>
                    <li class="sub-list">Item 3</li>
                    <li class="sub-list">Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("span").on("click", function(){
                $(".sub-list").toggleClass("show-menu");
            });
    
            $(document).on('click', function(event) {
              if (!$(event.target).closest('.sub-list').length)  {
                    $(".sub-list").removeClass("show-menu");
              }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: .sub-list or .sub-top ? Looks like should be sub-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `ev.stopPropagation()` for first handler. You click on `span` toggle class `show-menu`, then event bubble into document and thus you click out of `.sub-list` ( span is out of it ) second handler remove class

Or in second handler you need to check that you click on element out of `.sub-list` AND not on `span` element

```css
ul[class]:not(.show-menu) {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" media="screen" title="no title">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen" title="no title">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="top-list"><span>Item</span>
            <ul class="sub-top">
                <li class="sub-list">Item 1</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Item 2</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Item 3</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("span").on("click", function(ev){
            $(".sub-top").toggleClass("show-menu");
            ev.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).on('click', function(event) {
          if (!$(event.target).closest('.sub-list').length)  {
                $(".sub-top").removeClass("show-menu");
          }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Information about bubbling can be found here http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I just changed the .sub-top class back to .sub-list as this was required based on my css.

How does the event bubbling work on stop propagation? Could you explain by describing what exactly happens?

Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeConsterdine check next article http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bubble problem， cancel Bubble with span element.Have a try!